# What terminal foreground and background colors are good to reduce eye strain?

Tags: linux, terminal, theme

I'm wondering what settings people recommend for a terminal (xterm, iTerm2 etc) for minimizing eye strain.

I've so far used black foreground text on dull background color (like #C8AB95) - and that's been good. But wondering what the research shows in this area.

I came across Solarized theme recently that seems to have rave reviews. But the 'Solarized light' looks way too bright to me. Not sure how good that is for the eyes. That makes me also question 'Solarized dark'.

Anyways, wondering if people have any suggestions on this.

Just researching the best settings to use.

Comment: It's hard to expect anything but opinions on this website. I've always used black for background and light grey (#AAAAAA) for foreground.

Comment: if you're *wondering what the research shows*, then find some research, don't expect us to find it for you